# MENU_LOCAL_TASK Problem

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I am trying to add a tab to my menu in drupal and use this function, to test it:

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/classifieds'] = array(
    'title' => 'Action',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'my_module_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'weight' => 2,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

But nothing shows up. Why?

Answer (score 1):

You need an `access callback`, or at the very least, `access arguments` (`access callback` defaults to `user_access()` if not defined):

```
function my_module_menu() {
  $items['user/%user/classifieds'] = array(
    'title' => 'Action',
    'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    'page callback' => 'my_module_page',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
    'weight' => 2,
  );
  return $items;
}
```

Also make sure to rebuild the menu or clear the cache when making changes to `hook_menu()`.

Comment: hmmmm...I used the code you posted, but I still can not see the tab...:(

Comment: I also cleared the cached by emtying all tables with _cache in the name. Also the menu cache (cache_menu), but still no success.

Comment: Is the function `my_module_page` defined, and is it returning a string containing the output for the page? The only thing you need to rebuild when changing `hook_menu` is the menu. [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) lets you do this separately; otherwise, just go to *Site configuration* -> *Performance* and click the *Clear cached data* button.

Comment: wow. Cool. it is there. It seems that deleting the tables was not enough.

Another thing:
In D 6 we used this as access argument:  'access' => user_access(TPZCLASSIFIED_PERM_VIEW_PROFILETAB),

How do I have to use it in D6?

If I use it in the way above, I am not able to see the page because of missing permissions.

Comment: You need to define the permission using [`hook_perm()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_perm), which returns an array of strings. Then, you'll be able to use `array('permission name')` for `access arguments`. Just make sure the user has that permission set on *User management* -> *Permissions*.